# Sequelize querying both parent model and included model using [Op.or]

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I want to findAll `Bookings` where the booking has been paid.

A legacy booking has been paid if the `paymentAuthorised: boolean` attribute on the `Booking` table is true.

A new booking has been paid if the `paymentAuthorised: boolean` attribute on the `Payment` table is true and `type: string` attribute on the `Payment` table is 'booking'.

When I perform the following query it returns an error saying payments.paymentAuthorised not found.

```js
const bookings = await db.Booking.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: db.Payment,
        as: "payments",
      },
    ],
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
        {
          paymentAuthorised: { [Op.eq]: true },
        },
        {
          "$payments.paymentAuthorised$": { [Op.eq]: true },
          "$payments.type$": { [Op.eq]: "booking" },
        },
      ],
    },
    order: [["dateTime", "asc"]],
  });
```

Comment: share Booking and payment models, and full error log

Answer (score 0):

I worked this issue out in the end by logging the generated SQL. You need to add the following parameter: `subQuery: false`. This is so it generates an SQL query which includes the joins before the where.

```js
const bookings = await db.Booking.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: db.Payment,
        as: "payments",
      },
    ],
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
        {
          paymentAuthorised: { [Op.eq]: true },
        },
        {
          "$payments.paymentAuthorised$": { [Op.eq]: true },
          "$payments.type$": { [Op.eq]: "booking" },
        },
      ],
    },
    subQuery: false,
    order: [["dateTime", "asc"]],
  });
```